# SFTP file writes show completed in FileZilla but on server side 0 bytes written

Tags: linux, sftp, filezilla, vsftpd

Kind of a weird issue here.

We have a lot of data dropped on our SFTP, and sometimes we get a lot of files written with 0 bytes.  Upon checking the remote users SFTP Client (FileZilla) it shows the transfer was successful for the same amount of bytes, but when looking at SFTP logs it shows that the SFTP is opened with WRITE flags, but nothing happens until eventually the session is broken off about 2 hours later (I assume when they close FileZilla).  Here is a excerpt from the logs, some names redacted.

```
Mar 25 07:02:12 SERVER internal-sftp[13592]: realpath "/SERVER/IN/20150324/Part_4/20150324_Upload Tonight_SF_Table_4/20150321_SF_TT_04_KEVIN_0225.jpg"
Mar 25 07:02:13 SERVER internal-sftp[13592]: open "/SERVER/IN/20150324/Part_4/20150324_Upload Tonight_SF_Table_4/20150321_SF_TT_04_KEVIN_0225.jpg" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0666
Mar 25 09:13:40 SERVER internal-sftp[13592]: forced close "/SERVER/IN/20150324/Part_4/20150324_Upload Tonight_SF_Table_4/20150321_SF_TT_04_KEVIN_0225.jpg" bytes read 0 written 0
```

But when looking at the FileZilla transfer window it shows up as a successful transfer and the file sizes matches the real file size.

A screenshot of this:

[image]

As far as I know SFTP is supposed to have built in error-checking.  But this does not appear to be the case.  Does anyone know why this could be occurring?  It happened on quite a few files today.

Comment: Please include a FileZilla log.

Answer (score 0):

- The file was corrupted during transfer. This can be caused by
  connectivity issues between your computer and your server. We can
  partially test this by running 'traceroute domain.com' in Terminal
  (Mac users only, Windows uses tracert).
- Full disk space on the server. If the disk space is full on the
  server, it will cause issues similar to this with your upload.
- Charset issues. Your Grid charset is UTF-8. Occasionally, if you
  upload a file that isn't in this charset, you may encounter issues.
- The file was corrupted prior to upload. Please ensure that all files
  you upload are functioning correctly.